# List<WebElement> gives blank results

Tags: java, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

I am creating an automatic test for some webs and I'm using WebDriver and code that is written in Java. I am facing two issues here.

1. `click()` method is not working.
2. When I am trying to read a List of WebElement its showing blank. But it is showing correct `size()`.

My Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\back up\\Proj\\selenium\\Jars\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods");

List<WebElement> allBrands = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
List<WebElement> allBrandsInShowAll = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li/a"));

System.out.println("Total No of Brands "+(allBrands.size() + allBrandsInShowAll.size()));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")).click(); // This is not clicking on ShowAll Button
for(WebElement ele :allBrandsInShowAll) {
  System.out.println("Name=>"+ele.getText());
}

for(WebElement ele :allBrands) {
 System.out.println("Name=>"+ele.getText()); // Not printing the names of Brands
}
```

Comment: Did you validate xpath where you are trying to get elements? It might be possible that xpath could be wrong.

Comment: What you are trying to get here in **allBrandsInShowAll** ?

Comment: Xpath is correct. I validated it. please check this URL "http://www.americangolf.co.uk/golf-clubs/fairway-woods" allBrandsInShowAll should hold the values which comes after  [+Show All ] button click. [li values are under different div]

Comment: You should use this xpath for all brands : **//*[@id="secondary"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li** , It will return you size = 10.

Comment: but actual list of values under Brand is '13'

Comment: Yeah then please click on **show all** first then use my given xpath to get size of brands.

Comment: Also if you use this xpath **//div[@class='showall']/a** to get all *showall* then you will get size = 6. Then you can click on particular easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can simply use the css selector `div.showall` to click the ShowAll button from the Brands options.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.showall")).click();
   ```

Or even this xpath directly works

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")).click()
```

2. The parent element that you took for getting the `getText()` is not correct

   ```
   List<WebElement> allBrands = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
   ```

This will get all the `a` tag elements inside a single `li` child. You need to go inside all the `li` childs and get their anchor text.

You need something like this

```
    WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul"));

    List<WebElement> allBrands = parentElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("li >a"));

    for(WebElement ele :allBrands) {
     System.out.println("Name=>"+ele.getText()); 
    }
```

which prints output as

> Name=>CobraGolf
>   (14)
>
> Name=>CallawayGolf
>   (10)
>
> Name=>TaylorMade
>   (8)

---

Edit : OP mentioned he is not able to get the other brand options once `ShowAll` button is clicked. The reason is that they are inside another `div > ul` child.

Please modify your final code to this -

```
    //clicks on ShowAll button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

     //gets parent for Categories
     WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/ul"));

    //gets parent for Categories shown after clicking ShowAll
    WebElement secondParentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='secondary']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul"));


    List<WebElement> allBrands = parentElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("li >a"));
    List<WebElement> allBrandsInShowAll =secondParentElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("li >a"));

    System.out.println("Total No of Brands "+(allBrands.size() + allBrandsInShowAll.size()));

    for(WebElement ele :allBrands) {
     System.out.println("Name=>"+ele.getText()); 
    }

    for(WebElement ele :allBrandsInShowAll) {
         System.out.println("Name=>"+ele.getText()); 
        }

    driver.quit();

   }

    }
```

This prints all the categories inside the Brands-

Total No of Brands 13

- Name=>CobraGolf
  (14)
- Name=>CallawayGolf
  (10)
- Name=>TaylorMade
  (8)
- Name=>Ping
  (6)
- Name=>Benross
  (4)
- Name=>NikeGolf
  (2)
- Name=>Titleist
  (2)
- Name=>Wilson
  (2)
- Name=>WilsonStaff
  (2)
- Name=>Fazer
  (1)
- Name=>MizunoGolf
  (1)
- Name=>USKidsGolf
  (1)
- Name=>WilsonDeepRed
  (1)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If i use the cssSelector mentioned here.. i am getting "ElementNotInteractableException" and with the xpath "Show All" button doesn't get clicked. .. I need the values of inside Show all Button.. they are --> 
    MizunoGolf (1)
    USKidsGolf (1)
    WilsonDeepRed (1)
I was able to get the values from displayed UI portion

Comment: You can use the xpath also. I have added that too.

Comment: yeah Thanks demouser123, but I should be able to retrieve the values of inside Show All Button....But no luck :( so far..

Comment: Awesome Thanks for your help demouser123.